# Installing an npm package is crashing

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs, node-modules, npm-install

I was installing jest package as a dev dependency and it keeps on crashing and seems like not installing successfully. I noticed on my taskbar the 100% usage of cpu of node.js javascript runtime. How do I fix this?

[image]

I already tried turning my antivirus off (Kaspersky Internet Security)

Answer (score 0):

First, check to see if you might be trying to install a piece of malware. Search for it at https://socket.dev/ and review the results.

If it's a valid, maintained, and supported package, try installing with `--ignore-scripts` to see if the problem is a lifecycle script. If so, start looking at the package's lifecycle scripts. Maybe it's doing something you don't need done anyway.